# Accumulo shell get last inserted record

Tags: accumulo

Is there a way to scan the accumulo table to just return the last inserted record?  I'm setting the timestamp when I do my puts but I don't know how to use the accumulo shell to just return the last record or the max timestamp.

I want to be able to demonstrate that the last message received was indeed inserted into the table.  I need to be able to do this in the shell versus using the API due to time/funding constraints.

Looking for something like:

scan -t test -b ...

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Accumulo has only one index: the rowId. Any other looking requires searching through a large portion of the data.

For your request, to find the record in Accumulo with be largest timestamp requires an exhaustive search of every record in the table.

You're likely better off trying to prove existence of your record some other way (like using the rowId).

Comment: @gshepherd7 could have their ingest process store the rowId of the last record written somewhere else, and then using that information to scan for and verify it.